# Force update statements to take page locks in the same order?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, locking, deadlock

I have two update statements on the same table that take page locks in different orders. This leads to deadlocks.

- Process A owns an update lock on page 1, and requests an update lock on
  page 2.
- Process B owns an update lock on page 2, and wants an update
  lock on page 1.

How can I force both statements to take page locks in the same order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I force both statements to take page locks in the same order?

You can't.  Instead force them both to take a table lock with a TABLOCKX hint, or use an [Application Lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to serialize the sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You can force page access sequence in the SQL statement. You *may* be able to find a plan for each query that has the same access sequence then apply a plan guide. IIRC this is only a suggestion and the execution engine may not use it at runtime.

The pages are accessed and locked because rows on those pages are locked. If you can force the order in which the rows are touched, perhaps by a cursor, that will solve *this* problem. Of course you now have other problems.

Presumably the two queries aren't touching the same rows. SQL Server supports row locks. You have to define the tables and indexes accordingly.